# How do I get turbolinks to run a function once the DOM is completely loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapbox, turbolinks

`document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {});` is not working as expected. Mapbox throws the following error: `Uncaught Error: Container 'map' not found.` and the map only displays properly once I reload the page.

Some code for better understanding follows.

Javascript for mapbox import and setup:

```js
// app/javascript/plugins/init_mapbox.js

import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

const buildMap = () => {
  mapboxgl.accessToken = mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey;
  return new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
  });
};

const addMarkersToMap = (map, markers) => {
  markers.forEach((marker) => {
    new mapboxgl.Marker()
      .setLngLat([ marker.lng, marker.lat ])
      .addTo(map);
  });
};

const fitMapToMarkers = (map, markers) => {
  const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
  markers.forEach(marker => bounds.extend([ marker.lng, marker.lat ]));
  map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 70, maxZoom: 15 });
};

const initMapbox = () => {
  if (mapElement) {
    const map = buildMap();
    const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
    console.log(markers)
    addMarkersToMap(map, markers);
    fitMapToMarkers(map, markers);
  }
};

export { initMapbox };
```

Import in application.js:

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

import { initMapbox } from '../plugins/init_mapbox';

[...]

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  initMapbox();
});
```

The HTML:

```html
<!-- app/views/spaces/index.html.erb -->

[...]

<div id="map"
     style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"
     data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>"
     data-mapbox-api-key="<%= ENV['MAPBOX_API_KEY'] %>">
</div>

[...]
```

I am completely lost on this one. Any ideas? Anyone that has got this working?

Comment: Pls Paste some minimum code which demos the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning `mapElement` when the file is imported. Not when the DOM is ready or when turbolinks performs a page visit.

If you simply rewrite this code so that your functions take an element as an argument instead of relying on variables in the outside scope its trivial to solve it:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

const buildMap = (mapElement) => {
  mapboxgl.accessToken = mapElement.dataset.mapboxApiKey;
  return new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: mapElement,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
  });
};

const addMarkersToMap = (map, markers) => {
  markers.forEach((marker) => {
    new mapboxgl.Marker()
      .setLngLat([ marker.lng, marker.lat ])
      .addTo(map);
  });
};

const fitMapToMarkers = (map, markers) => {
  const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
  markers.forEach(marker => bounds.extend([ marker.lng, marker.lat ]));
  map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 70, maxZoom: 15 });
};

const initMapbox = (mapElement) => {
  const map = buildMap(mapElement);
  const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
  console.log(markers)
  addMarkersToMap(map, markers);
  fitMapToMarkers(map, markers);
};
```

You then query the DOM in your callback function:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
  if (mapElement) {
    initMapbox(mapElement);
  }
});
```

Additionally I don't know if this is a copy paste issue but your HTML is also missing a bracket in `<div id="map">`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and it works flawlessly now. Thanks a million!